# Использование собственного класса исключений

Tags: java, исключения

Создал свой класс исключений:

```
class ClassException extends IOException {

    public ClassException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

В другом классе пытаюсь пробросить исключение подобного типа:

```
public void amountOfPayment() throws ClassException {
    System.out.println("Indicate the amount of monthly child support: ");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    totalPercentage(Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine()));
}
```

Ругается на `reader.readLine()`:

> Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException

Что я упускаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `readLine` в классе `java.io.BufferedReader` пробрасывает `IOException`, которое является родительским (более общим), чем ваше `ClassException`. Поэтому его нельзя заменить на более конкретное (ваше) в `throws`, ибо нет никаких гарантий того, что проброшено будет именно `ClassException`, а не само `IOException` или одно из других многочисленных исключений, наследующихся от `IOException`.

---

Ситуация весьма похожа на следующую (возможно, она более проста для понимания). Создание своего класса, расширяющего `Number`:

```
class MyNumber extends Number { ... }
```

и попытка некорректного использования с объектом, который является `Number` (`class Integer extends Number`), но не является `MyNumber`:

```
public MyNumber get()
{
    Integer n = 0;
    return n;
}
```

---

Одним из возможных решений в этом случае (по аналогии с ответом @SergeyGornostaev) является создание в `MyNumber` конструктора, принимающего `Number`:

```
class MyNumber extends Number
{
    public MyNumber(Number number) { ... }
    ...
}
```

и возвращение из метода `get` нового объекта `MyNumber`:

```
public MyNumber get()
{
    Integer n = 0;
    return new MyNumber(n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Причины правильно и подробно описал Regent. Решение же может быть таким:

```
public void amountOfPayment() throws ClassException {
    System.out.println("Indicate the amount of monthly child support: ");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        totalPercentage(Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine()));
    }
    catch (IOException exc) {
        ClassException myExc = new ClassException(exc.getMessage());
        myExc.initCause(ioExc);
        throw myExc();
    }
}
```

Или проще, если переопределить [конструктор принимающий Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception-java.lang.Throwable-):

```
class ClassException extends IOException {
    public ClassException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ClassException(Throwable exc) {
        super(exc);
    }
}

try {
    totalPercentage(Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine()));
}
catch (IOException exc) {
    throw new ClassException(exc);
}
```

Comment: Я отдебажил и вижу, что при нарошном вызове исключения, оно даже не заходит в **ClassException**

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: У меня при возникновении исключение, программа сразу выводит трейс и завершается, а как при этом не выводить stacktrace, а вывести своё сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: У меня при возникновении исключение, программа сразу выводит трейс и завершается, а как при этом не выводить stacktrace, а вывести своё сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: В коде вызывающем `amountOfPayment` перехватывайте исключение `ClassException`.